# Run Cisco VPN and SonicWall VPN on same Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I need to have Cisco VPN client and SonicWall VPN client on same machine. There are some compatibility issues with these 2 applications that does not allow them to be present on same computer. I did find some workarounds, but they did not work for me.

I don't need connect to both VPN at the same time, just that both should be available in same Windows account and I can not either one based on my need.

Comment: It's certainly possible on Windows XP, because I have Cisco AnyConnect and also the SonicWall client on an XP laptop I use, and they work fine.

Comment: @AlanB, I am referring to Cisco VPN Client. Not Cisco AnyConnect. Thanks.